# Finding circular references in VB6

Tags: vb6

I'm trying to compile some code in VB6, and it tells me "Circular dependencies between modules." It doesn't deign to tell me which modules have these dependencies.

Is there any way I can find more information about the problem?

Comment: that not is the response but at least you have other point to view http://www.vbaccelerator.com/home/vb/code/techniques/Dealing_with_Circular_References/article.asp

Comment: @Carlos unfortunately that for two classes that hold a reference to each other which doesn't produce the error Xodarap is getting. The error Xodarap is when a chain of COM references forms a circular reference which is not allowed under the rules of COM

Answer (score 4):

You have projects that form a circular chain of references. Use the menu Project and then References to see which other projects your are references. Then do this for all the other projects that are part of the application. Draw a rough graph of what links to what and at some point you will find the references loop back to one of the projects.

You only need to focus on the references to projects you created yourself. Also you will need to check any projects you created that includes custom ActiveX Controls. This is found under the menu Project->Components.

Likely you will find that there is only a handful of classes you are referencing. In that case you can separate them out into another activex DLL/library and have the original projects reference that instead of each other.

The reason this issue arises is because COM relies the type libraries embedded in the library to call the classes and their methods. Referenced libraries are included in this typelib in a manner similar to a include file in C. Circular references have no "bottom" so COM can't get to the bottommost library to form the typelib.

Comment: I eventually figured it out by just commenting out the `Implements` and seeing when it started compiling. I was hoping that there was a quicker solution though - I work for a large company and had I been dealing with a bigger project it would've taken forever to do it manually.

Comment: @Xodarap: Typelibs include only public methods/properties of the classes in a project. If you try not to include "foreign" data-types in these no importlib is generated. Keeping external libs to a minimum is a best practice. I'm regularly using `As Object` instead of strongly-typed interfaces and `As Long` instead of "foreign" enums on my public interfaces.

Comment: IF you use As Object be sure to test for performance. As it takes ten time as long for VB6 to parse the references to a late bound object. In addition you lose all the benefits of type checking at compile time. Like anything you need to be aware of the pros and cons of the feature.

Comment: @RS Conley: I'm always casting `As Object` params/properties to local strongly-typed vars before using these. This as a sanity check.

Answer (score 1):

I found another situation where this comes up and the solution for it. If you rename the library (Project Name under Project / Properties) and you pass object references with fully-qualified type names like:

```
Sub Example(ByVal myControl As Library.Classname)
```

Then you have to search and replace < Library.> with < NewLibraryName.> (including a leading space and trailing dot to prevent unwanted matches).  Do this for FRM, BAS, CLS and CTL file extensions.

```
Sub Example(ByVal myControl As NewLibraryName.Classname)
```

Note that before you can do the above, you have to fix up CTL and FRM files to get the project to load in the first place (before you can get the circular dependency error). Similar to the above, that process involves replacing "Begin Library." with "Begin NewName."

Enjoy!